# How can I make a Visual Studio 2017 custom editor refresh the text view?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I have created a Visual Studio custom editor extension (implementing `ITagger<T>`). It works perfectly and applies syntax highlighting according to the domain specific language behind it. Nonetheless, when I edit the text, VS re-tags and re-formats *only* the edited line.

However, when a particular line changes, I need to force re-formatting all the visible lines following the edited line. I do not know how to do this. I tried many alternatives, including responding the `Changed` event of the `TextBuffer` behind.

Can you help me with ideas, or sample source code to custom editor implementations that handle this issue? The built-in C# editor does it: when I edit a line, and it becomes a multi-line comment, the text view is changed accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I am currently trying to use `ITagger` and `IErrorTag` to add red underlines in the Visual Studio editor. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed. If you have your code on Github and you can provide me the link or show me how you did it, it will be a great help for me

Answer (score 0):

The extension code Formatter could format the class file and arrange fields, properties and methods as per StyleCop rules. Maybe it is an extension you want to get:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.CodeFormatter

Comment: Jack, thanks for the idea, but I'm looking for something else. I created my own DSL, support it with a custom tagger that provides syntax highlighting. The issue I cannot solve is this: a custom tagger re-formats only the currently edited line, and I do not know how to force it to re-format other lines (apply syntax highlights after the edit to them) . In my DSL, changing the current line may require to re-tag subsequent lines, too.

Answer (score 0):

One crude way is to close the document and open it again.

```
string path = dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;
dte.ActiveDocument.Save();
dte.ActiveDocument.Close();
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(path);
```

Although, I hope there is a better way to deal with this issue.

**Edit:** Well, I think I found a better way.

An event is declared in your tagger class (which implements ITagger interface). Raising the interface does the job flawlessly.

Comment: Tushar, thanks for the work you invested to answer my questions. Unfortunately, raising the event does not solve this issue. The event can be used by entities attached to your custom ITagger class to get notified about that your tagger has meda changes.

Comment: Can you describe how to raise an event on the ITagger interface? There doesn't seem to be any way to do this? All I can do is subscribe to the event but I need to raise the event.